# What is the importance and implication of Random Intercept in a mixed-model?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

Is it necessary to *always* include the random intercept in a mixed model? Can we drop it sometimes? How can we know *when* it is or it is not possible to drop it? Would its exclusion adversely affect the model specification? Is that effect always considerable? How can we know when it is considerable and when it is not? Are AIC and BIC the indicators of a proper model with or without the random intercept?

And also why and how is it important?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AIC can be used to indicate a better fitting model relative to the number of parameters but no summary measure of the model's fit is going to tell you what a proper model is.

Comment: Can I pick the model which accords with reality (or at least my theory) better?! Actually my models do not change considerably by removing the random intercept. In some of them, the intercept-less model is the more logical (in accordance with common sense), and in some others, vice versa. (but again, the change is not big)

Comment: Matching reality trumps mindless model fitting. But you should be cautious that perhaps you want to modify what you think reality is. It sounds like, from your repeated comment questions, your whole point of asking was to remove the random intercept. You usually need a good 'reality' justification like the one Peter Flom mentioned. Perhaps you should add that to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot John. Yes sort of. Actually both my models are good and as I said with slight changes. I can use each of them, or even can report both of them and discuss this reality matching in the discussion part. Even I take back that one model fits "my" reality better. Now that I double think it, I see each fits some part of "my" reality (and there is a huge overlap between the two models) better. So each of them is sound and a little bit partial at the same time. Some variables seem to correlate to DV in reality and it is not something mysteriously hidden. One model approves ...

Comment: ... all of them except a couple of IVs (for example X1 and X2). The other one approves all of them too except another couple of IVs (and it also approves the first IVs [X1 and X2]). ... I had first added this to my question, but later thought that a specific question will be of no interest to people except myself, but a general question like "what is the importance of random intercept" is something quite missing in all the resources I could see and thus might be much more useful than my "own" concern. This is why I omitted it in the first place. Thanks a lot again John. :)

Comment: Regardless of my own concern, I am still curious what is the importance of the random intercept! I tried to read about it but every PDF document was full of mathematical symbols that unlike the fixed intercept which is something much easier to understand both mathematically and visually, were not easy for me. So my main question is yet remaining unanswered (that why and how the random intercept is important).

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the mixed model is being used to adjust for temporal or clustering effects.

In a longitudinal model, a random intercept says that each subject can have its (or his or her) own starting point. Typically, random slopes are also an option, and these relate to the effect of time - each subject can have a different rate of increase. Here, dropping the intercept might make sense, it is sensible to suppose that all subjects started at the same point.

In a clustered data situation (e.g. students in classrooms) it is harder (at least for me) to see when you would drop the intercept term, but maybe I haven't had enough coffee yet. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much for your informative (and caffeinated) response dear Peter.

Comment: What do you think about using AIC and BIC for choosing the right model between the intercept-included and interceptless models? I mean picking up the one with greater AIC/BIC? I see whenever the AIC is greater (regardless of the intercept being there or not), the model is closer to my expectation.

Comment: That is one approach (be careful, though, depending on the implementation, it may be a lower AIC is better - that is how SAS does it, for instance). If there is no strong substantive reason for including a random intercept, maybe AIC or BIC is best.

Comment: WOW THANKS Then those consistencies in AIC and reality matching were not coincidental. :) Many many many thanks :)

Comment: On a side note, as I said (above) to John, I might even report both models and discuss them. So I will state that these few questionable variables which changed between significant and non-significant from model to model were marginally significant and need further evaluation with better test powers, but the variables significant in both models are definitely significant.

Answer (score 2):

The highly recommended paper by [Barr et al](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf). (2013) discusses, among others, models with random slopes but without random intercepts (p. 262). Their final recommendation clearly prefer these models to random intercept only models (p. 267):

> LMEMs with maximal random slopes, but missing either random
>   correlations or within-unit random intercepts, performed nearly as
>   well as ‘‘fully’’ maximal LMEMs, with the exception of the case where
>   p-values were determined by MCMC sampling. In addition, there was
>   slight additional anticonservativity relative to the maximal model
>   for the models missing within-unit random intercepts. This suggests
>   that when maximal LMEMs fail to converge, dropping within-unit random
>   intercepts or random correlations are both viable options for simplifying the random effects structure.

and

> From the point of view of overall Type I error rate, we can rank the
>   analyses for both within- and between-items designs in order of
>   desirability:
>
> 1. min-F' , maximal LMEMs, ‘‘near-maximal’’ LMEMs missing within-unit random intercepts or random correlations, and model
>      selection LMEMs using backward selection and/or testing slopes using
>      the ‘‘best path’’ algorithm.

Barr, D. J., Levy, R., Scheepers, C., & Tily, H. J. (2013). [Random effects structure for confirmatory hypothesis testing: Keep it maximal](http://idiom.ucsd.edu/~rlevy/papers/barr-etal-2013-jml.pdf). *Journal of Memory and Language*, 68(3), 255–278. doi:10.1016/j.jml.2012.11.001

Comment: The Barr paper is not as generalizable as people think. The particular kind of data examined does have generally strong random slopes. Some kinds of data do not. In that case the random slope is an additional unjustified parameter. It should be taken from the Barr paper that the recommendations are constrained to the limited field for which they were tested and that the paper can be used as a model for examining their own data rather than extrapolating the findings to data analysis in general.

Comment: Many thanks dear Henrik for the hints and this nice paper. This is awesome. Let me ask this from you too: What do you think about using AIC and BIC for choosing the right model between the intercept-included and interceptless models? I mean picking up the one with greater AIC/BIC? I see whenever the AIC is greater (regardless of the intercept being there or not), the model is closer to my expectation.

Comment: John you mean we should still try to keep the random intercept? Could you too answer to this question that "is it valid to use AIC/BIC to select between intercept-included and intercept-free models?"

Comment: @Vic If you are interested in whether or not the random intercept is necessary you could also try a likelihood ratio test between the models (i.e. `anova()`). Sounds somewhat more appropriate if this is the only thing you are interested in.

Comment: Many thanks again. Yes that is my only concern right now (to see if I should keep it or drop it, especially when both models are reasonable and similar with slight differences). Everything is fine, but remains deciding between the two model types. Sure I would do that. Thanks a lot again for this gem. :)

Comment: About Barr et al., it is important to keep in mind that their conclusions about omitting random intercepts vs. random slopes do apply to the particular experimental design they studied (the "fully crossed" design), but do *not* necessarily apply in general! Which components matter most depends on the proportion of predictor variance that varies within- and between-units. If all predictor variance is between, it is the intercept that matters. If data are highly unbalanced and many missing values, both will matter. So the correct conclusion is more complicated than "Omit intercepts, not slopes."

Comment: Thanks Jake (informative answer btw, I suggest you answering this as a full answer). Glad to see you! (I noticed your comment now!)